# How to change connect multiple id to change color using input in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, telnet

I have a webpage that I want to be manipulated remotely or by a touch screen when input mute or muteon text. This is the current code I have to where if clicked the muteon will turn red, and if init is change to on then when clicked the color will change to green. I want to know how would I incorporate this with the html code I want manipulated with id="text" and id="text1". Please advise. I want the ability to input mute and the id of text or text1 turns green and muteon where text or text1 will turn red. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="muteon">MuteOn</div>
<div id="mute">Mute</div>
<input onclick="off()"
```

Javascript:

```
function off() {
  document.getElementById("muteon").style.color = 'red';
}

function on() {
  document.getElementById("mute").style.color = 'green';
}
```

HTML Code I want manipulated

```
<div class="flex-col-c p-t-0 p-b-10 respon1">
<h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-10">
<font color="white" style="font-weight: 600;">
<p id="text1"></font></p>
</h1>

<h1 class="l1-txt1 txt-center p-t-0 p-b-60"><p>
<font color="crimson" style="font-weight: 600;">
<p id="text"></font></p>
```

Comment: You want to change colors or perhaps just show one element and hide another?

Comment: @RoboRobok Both would be feasible. But Ideally I want for only the color of id "text" and "text1" to change when mute or muteon is inputed in a text box

Comment: You shouldn't have tags like this `<font><p></font></p>`. In fact ou shouldn't have <font> at all. For example use `<p id="text" style="color: crimson; font-weight: 600"></p>` instead

Comment: But you want to display both options at the same time? Start from deciding on the design. You can either display both options and highlight the selected one, or just display one of them at a time.

Comment: Yes, I currently have "text" and "text1" displayed at the same time. I want them both to stay being displayed at the same time. I just would like the option to input text saying mute or muteon that will then change the color of id text and text1. @RoboRobok

Answer (score 3):

I would just toggle class of the parent:

```html
<div class="mute-container">
    <div class="mute-on">Mute On</div>
    <div class="mute-off">Mute Off</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function toggleMute() {
    document.querySelector('.mute-container').classList.toggle('on');
}
```

CSS:

```css
.mute-container.on .mute-on {
    color: red;
}

.mute-container:not(.on) .mute-off {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: How do I toggle to muteon? mute works fine but I'm not sure how I would toggle to muteon or red. Also is there away for me to link this to id="text" and id="text1" so that these colors change when toggled

Comment: My answer toggles the state, so you could have it as a toggling button, something like iOS has, where clicking on it toggles it. Whenever you call `toggleMute()`, it toggles the state.

Comment: Okay and is there away for me to link this to text and text1 id so that I can toggle there states as well to change there color

Comment: Yes, just try to understand what that code does and you can then use this pattern anywhere you want. The thing is that my solution is more CSS-driven, entire look is defined by the container either having certain class or not.